# Codeigniter ajax country state dropdown is not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

Hi I am having registration form which inlcudes countries and stated dropdown.Not able to get the states list after slecting countries.In Console getting response as page not found.Here is my code.

Controller:

```
function signup()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error"> ','</span>');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('country_id','Country Name','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('state_id','State Name','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('city_id','City Name','required');
    if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)   
   {    
    $data['country'] = $this->signup_model->getcountry();  
    $data['mainpage']='signup';
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
    }
else
    {
        $this -> signup_model -> insertprofiledetails();
        $this->flash->success('<h2>Profile Details Added Successfully!</h2>');
        redirect('welcome/add');
    }
}

public function ajax_state_list($country_id)
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('signup_model');
    $data['state'] = $this->signup_model->getstate($country_id);
    $this->load->view('ajax_get_state',$data);
}
```

Model:

```
function getcountry()
 {
    $this -> db -> select('*');
    $query = $this -> db -> get('countries');       
    return $query->result();
 }

  function getstate($country_id='')
 {
    $this -> db -> select('states.*');
    $this -> db -> where('country_id', $country_id);
    $query = $this -> db -> get('states');
    return $query->result();
 }
```

View:

```
<script>
    function getstatedetails(id)
    {
        //alert('this id value :'+id);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>welcome/ajax_state_list '+id,
            data: id='cat_id',
            success: function(data){
                //alert(data);
                $('#old_state').html(data);
        },
         });
    }
</script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-address2">Country</label>                                              
    <select name="country_details" class="form-control countries" id="country_details" onChange="getstatedetails(this.value)">
          <option value="" selected="selected" >Select Country</option>
           <?php foreach($country as $count): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $count->country_id; ?>"><?php echo $count->country_name; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?> 
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-address2">State</label>
    <select name="select_state" class="form-control countries" id="old_state" onChange="getcitydetails(this.value)">
           <option selected="selected">Select State</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

ajax_get_state:

```
<select name="select" onChange="getstatedetails(this.value)">
 <option value="" selected="selected" >Select State</option>
 <?php foreach($state as $stt): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $stt->state_id; ?>"><?php echo $stt->state_name; ?></option>
 <?php endforeach; ?> 
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks your forget use `/` after `ajax_state_list`

Edit your jQuery script :

```
url: '<?php echo base_url();?>welcome/ajax_state_list/'+id,
```

Comment: if my answer is useful for you, please accept my answer. Thanks